# Is there any abstraction layer for Apache JackRabbit repository?

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I was wondering if there is a library that provides developers with some sort of abstraction for accessing JackRabbit more easily.

I'm aware of the fact that there are a few CMS that utilizes jackRabbit and that have such an abstraction.

Something that would cover all this :

```
InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

Node folder = session.getNode("/absolute/path/to/folder/node");
Node file = folder.addNode("Article.pdf","nt:file");
Node content = file.addNode("jcr:content","nt:resource");
Binary binary = session.getValueFactory().createBinary(stream);
content.setProperty("jcr:data",binary);
```

Example :

```
JCRUtils.addFile(File file, String Title, String description, Map<String, String> properties, MixinType mixinType)
```

I'm going to implement this layer myself, but I wanted to be sure, that I won't "implement a wheel" that has been implemented.

Comment: You are fully familiar with JSR-170?  There is a "behave like Windows file server" mode which may be easier to work with.

Comment: I am, I'm just checking, because I rather contribute to some open source project that already exists, instead of programing something from scratch. I believe that everybody who is programatically using JackRabbit is writing this abstraction layer...

Comment: I just created the basic abstraction for what I need and I must admit that the library would have to be damn fancy to be useful :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a project that tries to simplify things: [Jackrabbit JCR Commons](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/JcrCommons). Maybe you could help in this project?

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I realized right after I asked the question here. I'll see what I can do. If the layer I'm doing will be universal enough, I'll put it on github and submit a proposal on Jira so you can check that out ... It is relatively easy to make Utils for getting stuff, but not for setting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [FS2 project](http://robertjchristian.github.com/fs2/) on GitHub.  It abstracts at the URI level and is very simple to use.  You can create a custom repository very simply using a template pattern.  It's a lightweight answer to JSR 170.  There's a test harness built into the framework... just check out the example in-memory and file implementations.